# simple way to put div side by side

Tags: html

I am looking for a really simple way to put divs side by side without without using css file or external reference.

Why is this not working when i use float left?

```
<div style="float:left;border:solid 5px red;width:100px;"> 
    This is div 1. alerted to float element left
    
</div>

<br>

<div style="border:5px solid green;width:100px;" > 
    This is div 2. should show side by side to div 1
</div>
```

It shows 2nd div below it instead of next to it.

[image]

Comment: you're using inline css and saying without CSS? What !!!

Comment: A real simple way without using CSS would be to create a table with one row and two cells. But since you're using CSS in your own example, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: 392 / 5 000
Résultats de traduction
HTML and CSS are complementary: HTML is a text-based markup language and CSS is a presentation language using CSS markup. If it is possible to display text without adding a CSS description, your page will be displayed with the CSS descriptions chosen by default in your browser, which here cannot allow you to display your page as you wish.

Comment: @OMiShah apologies. i mean without css file or external reference. edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can put them side by side by changing the div tag into span tag and removing the 
 tag, cause the span tag  is an inline tag, like this :

```
<span style="float:left;border:solid 5px red;width:100px;"> 
    This is div 1. alerted to float element left
    
</span>



<span style="border:5px solid green;width:100px;" > 
    This is div 2. should show side by side to div 1
</span>
```

Or you can put both items in a container and then use display: flex; to put them side by side like this :
but you have to remove the 
 tag

```
<div class="container" style="display:flex;">
<div style="float:left;border:solid 5px red;width:100px;"> 
    This is div 1. alerted to float element left
    
</div>



<div style="border:5px solid green;width:100px;" > 
    This is div 2. should show side by side to div 1
</div>   

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex > div {
  flex-basis: 100px;
}

.bordred_red {
  border:solid 5px red;
}

.bordred_green {
  border:5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="bordred_red"> 
      This is div 1. alerted to float element left
  </div>
  <div class="bordred_green"> 
      This is div 2. should show side by side to div 1
  </div>
</div>
```